# Subtraction of hex strings in mysql

Tags: xampp, mariadb

I accidentally generated my tables with some columns as hex strings when they should be decimals. Whoops. But anyway, as part of a query, I subtract them:

[image: hexsub]

I can't find documentation, so I come here to ask: What exactly is the meaning of subtraction between two (hex) strings? it doesn't seem to be converting them to base16 ints and subtracting, it's not the number of different characters. Subtracting 2 different strings creates a difference of 0. So what does it mean?

Comment: Is it MYSQL or MariaDB?

Comment: **Accidentally** and then filled a bunch of rows. So delete that duff columns and start again

Comment: @RiggsFolly MariaDB, technically. I'm not looking for how to fix the columns, I can figure that out. I just wanted to know what subtraction means.

Comment: Why are "amounts" being stored as hex???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings are interpreted letter by letter from left to right as number until the interpretation has to stop. These numbers are subtracted. If even the first character is a letter, 0 is the result.

```
2f - 1f is 1
f - 4xxx is -4
761xxx - facb is 761
```

Some further tests:

```
select '1aaa' - '-1.1bbbb' is 2.1
select '.1aaa' - '-1.1bbbb' is 1.2000000000000002
```

official documentation: [mysql/type-conversion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)